# Why is ASP.NET 4 / IIS7 html-encoding my query string?

Tags: iis-7, xss

We've switched one of our test environments to using .NET 4 on IIS7. Production is using .NET 2.

Certain urls, such as

```
http://www.example.com/page.aspx?param1=<foo>&param2=<foo>
```

Aren't getting caught by our stringindex code that looks for < or > in Request.Url.ToString(). Why? Because they're showing up as `&lt;foo&gt;` when we check. This worked in .NET 2.

What is going on?

NOTE: there are no mistakes in the formatting. I really mean *HTML* encode.

Answer (score 0):

All data in query string needs to be URL Encoded to be able to parse correctly, so if you want to grab what you entered you need to URL Decode the query string.

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx :

URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.